# Can't receive any ETH for Rinkeby test Network?help?

Tags: solidity

I've tried linking the twitter tweet asking for funds into a Metamask Rinkeby wallet for testing practice purposes. If anybody on the Rinkeby test Network could send me some funds, I whole-heartedly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MyCrypto faucet, they have been reliable for a while.

https://app.mycrypto.com/faucet